# Notice: Undefined index: exit in

Tags: php

Hola soy nuevo en esto y me da este error.

Notice: Undefined index: exit in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\AdminLTE\cerrar-sesion.php on line 3

la idea es cerrar sesion.

```html
<?php
  session_start();
  $cerrar_sesion = $_GET['cerrar_sesion'];
  if($cerrar_sesion){
    session_destroy();
  }
 ?>
```

---

```html
<div class="pull-right">
<a href="login.php?$cerrar_sesion=true" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Cerrar sesion</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que tengas el login por un lado y el logout por otro! Y para pasar la variable en `a` debes hacerlo asi: `login.php?cerrar_sesion=<?=$cerrar_sesion=true;?>`

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes se presenta en la forma en la que estas enviando el parámetro por `$_GET`, especificamente en el `$` antes del nombre del parametro, pero puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="pull-right">
<a href="login.php?cerrar_sesion=1" class="btn btn-success btn-flat">Cerrar sesion</a>
</div>
```

Puedes utilizar `1` en lugar de `true` y `0` en lugar de `false` y te funcionara de la misma manera. Con esto ya podrás utilizarlo en `php` como lo tienes actualmente:

```
session_start();
$cerrar_sesion = $_GET['cerrar_sesion'];
if($cerrar_sesion){
  session_destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yo agregaría:

```
$cerrar_sesion = $_GET['cerrar_sesion'];
if($cerrar_sesion){
    session_destroy();

    if(isset($_COOKIE['email'])) {
        unset($_COOKIE['email']);
        setcookie('email', '', time()-86400);
    }
}
```

Comment: que agregaste?, por favor lee [answer] y edita para explicar que hiciste

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por las respuesta.

a la final lo hice es cambiar por isset

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['cerrar_sesion'])) {
session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: recuerda que puedes aceptar tu respuesta, para que los demás usuarios puedan encontrar fácil la respuesta